# Dynamic pages content

Tags: php

I would like to change the site content in realation to a GET variable from the URL for exmaple:

```
www.example.com/index.php?a=products
www.example.com/index.php?a=contact
```

My site contains 3 blocks:

- navigator
- left block
- right block

The block that would be dynamic is the right one.
Using require/include is impossible because it's not the first thing I print and then I'll probably get a headers already sent error.

```
<?php
echo "Navigator will be printed here";
echo "Left block will be printed here";
require 'dynamic_content.php';
```

So how can I do that?

Comment: Why would you get a "headers already sent error"? Do you use session_start() or header() in `dynamic_content.php`?

Comment: yes I do, also javascript code to change window location.

Answer (score 1):

Either redesign your project structure (recommended) or use [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/book.outcontrol.php) functions:

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo "Navigator will be printed here";
echo "Left block will be printed here";
require 'dynamic_content.php';

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: I would LOVE to re-dedesign my website. Please instruct me.

Comment: I agree, I would recommend you use an existing framework and not re-invent the wheel.

As a simple starter, try [Code Igniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)

Comment: If using an existing framework is not applicable, I would recommend you reading this series of articles on Nettuts+ on [Creating you own PHP 5 framework](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-a-php5-framework-part-1/)

Comment: @ImriPersiado Mosab Ahmad is right, you should look into a good PHP framework such as CakePHP, Code Igniter, ZendFramework, ... However, I wouldn't recommend that Nettuts+ link (Singleton pattern = bad in this case).

Comment: Thank you guys! and do you reccomand to a begginer php to use a framework?